# Spring Data Neo4j Creating Dynamic Labels at Node (Java Node Entity) level

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

Springboot Application
Spring Data Neo4j
Connecting to Aura DB
I have a Node Entity called Group. I want to add Dynamic Labels at Node Level

```
public class Group implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
private String id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Neo4j supports dynamic labels via the `@DynamicLabels` annotation.

```
public class Group implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
  private String id;

  @DynamicLabels
  public Set<String> myDynamicLabels;

}
```

More about this can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.annotations.node.dynamic.labels).